# Filter question list on substring of metavalue

Tags: posts, filters, post-meta

On the admin page I want to filter posts based on meta values. I know using the `pre_get_posts` hook will allow me to filter based on specific meta values, however I want to filter on a certain substring in the meta value. For example:

my meta values are full names. I know my current user's name is John Smith, I don't want him to see the posts of anyone with the last name of Smith in this meta value.

I have seen posts like this, where I can filter on a specific meta value, but not on substring of a meta value. This would likely be achieved using SQL's `LIKE` feature.

Comment: So can you confirm if `LIKE` is sufficient? Because it's pretty easy, [see the codex on meta queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: `LIKE` is sufficient. Using the link you gave I was able to do what I needed, problem solved.